# Remove the link to the upstream repository in Bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

Let's say I have a git repository `parent` in bitbucket. I fork `parent` to `child` (I guess Bitbucket implements this as a `clone` operation, but I am not sure). Now I commit changes to `child`. From time to time Bitbucket notifies me that the `parent` is behind `child` and asks me whether I want to sync them. I don't like this because in my case `parent` is a template repository for new projects, so changes in instantiated projects should never be pushed back to the template repository. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I don't like this because in my case parent is a template repository for new projects, so changes in instantiated projects should never be pushed back to the template repository

Then don't [fork it](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Forking+a+Repository).

- Create a new empty repo on BitBucket
- clone your BitBucket template repo on your computer
- change the remote "`origin`" of your local repo to the new remote BitBucket repo you just created:

  ```
  git remote set-url origin https://username@bitbucket.org/username/newrepo
  ```
- push to the new repo

  ```
  git push -u origin master
  ```

That way, both BitBucket repos won't have any link between them, and BitBucket won't remind you of any merge to do between them.

Comment: OK, looks good. How about already existing repositories that have already been forked? Can I still remove the link? I guess I can apply your method to the ``child`` repository to create a new ``child2`` which has all the history of ``child``, but no ties to ``parent``. Then I remove ``child`` in bitbucket, and finally rename ``child2`` to ``child`` and upload. Would that work?

Comment: @user2683038 yes, that would work. I would recommend, for the push step, a `git push --mirror` (to be sure to push everything)